# Can a plugin force download an asset from third-party source like Amazon S3?

Tags: plugin-development, assets

I have created a plugin that takes a form post, retrieves an asset id and am trying to have the browser start the download process. Is this possible if using a third party source like AmazonS3?  If so what may be wrong with this plugin controller method?

```
public function actionDownloadAsset()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();
    $id = craft()->request->getRequiredPost("id");

    $attributes = array('id' => $id);
    $element = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset)->limit(1)->find($attributes);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($element->filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $element->filesize);
    readfile($element->url);
}
```

Everytime I try the plugin from front end I get a page not found.  I have made sure the from is posting to the controller method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
public function actionDownloadAsset()
{
  $this->requirePostRequest();
  $id = craft()->request->getRequiredPost("id");
  $attributes = array('id' => $id);
  $element = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset)->first($attributes);


  $file = $entry->url;
  $name = $entry->filename;

  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($name));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');

  readfile($file);
}
```

To get access to the file url I had to array_shift the $element returned from getCriteria.  Then I had to exclude the file size header. This was ultimately causing the "this webpage is not available". Not sure the reason.

`header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($entry->size))`

Comment: My only concern is, could I run into memory issues for the file being downloaded?

Comment: Oh, right. You won't need the array_shift, if you change it to $element = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset)->first($attributes); Not sure what's going on with the header size.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a Craft 404, then it sounds like it's not even making it to your controller's action.

Likely, you haven't [allowed anonymous access](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions) to your controller globally or that action in particular.

Comment: I added "allowed anonymous access" to the controller.  If I add a Dump and Exit it gets as far as the element. It doesn't give a Craft 404 just "This webpage is not available".

Comment: Check either your Apache error logs or craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log and see if any fatal errors are getting logged.

Comment: No errors in either logs. In my code above am I getting the specific asset properly?

Comment: Yeah, that should work fine. Check the response in your browser's console?